# Using a Java method in an SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I made a program to parse an XML file with, and now I want to put the data in a database,
a PostgreSQL database. However, I cannot use

executeUpdate(INSERT INTO Titles(name) VALUES (parseTitles())),

since it wants a boolean. The string that comes out of the function looks like this:
'a','b','c','d'

Is there a way to solve this, or am I bound to put all the data in manually?

Comment: Can you give us some more code and a deeper explanation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I strongly suspect that [this](https://github.com/tada/pljava) may help. Another suggestion is to first execute your `parseTitles()` and then execute your insert once you have the values.

Answer (score 0):

java runs first and then the SQL statement is sent to the db to be executed.

You probably need something like this to produce the right sql statement:

executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO Titles(name) VALUES (" + parseTitles() + ")" );